# Display only icons using bootstrap nav walker in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using bootstrap nav walker to display my menus on wordpress theme 
It was good for main menu using icons with beside texts

Now, I want a menu with socials badges which must display only icons. when I try to make navigation label blank or ' ' (space) it didn't work while updating.

So, I just want to know is there any way to hide navigation label and making the output code as

`<li classes[] id[] ><a href="link" title="navigation label"><i class="title attribute"></i></a></li>`

instead of

`<li classes[] id[] ><a href="link" title="navigation label"><i class="title attribute"></i> navigation lable</a></li>`

I've tried using `<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>` as **navigation label** but anchor is using this as a title also.

Comment: "... navigation label blank or ' ' (space) it didn't work while updating. ..." - Where do you update it? In code or admin screen? Also, can you try modify that walker?

Comment: in admin panel only I can't modify that walker because am very new to word press theme development

Comment: Ok. got it. If you still having trouble, please copy paste the walker class code from functions.php, let others have a look, if you don't have any problem.